# Check if position has already been taken Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

```
Board = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(Board[0], '|', Board[1], '|', Board[2])
print(Board[3], '|', Board[4], '|', Board[5])
print(Board[6], '|', Board[7], '|', Board[8])
Player_Input = int(input("Choose a number between 1-9: "))
while Board[Player_Input - 1] == Player_Input:
    Board[Player_Input - 1] = 'X'
```

So this is a short example of the code that works in my program.

```
while Board[Player_Input - 1] != Player_Input:
    Player_Input = int(input("Already taken. Choose another position: "))
```

I've tried using this 2 lines to check if a position is already taken but it somehow does not work. I've also tried to use this:

```
while Board[Player_Input - 1] == 'X' or Board[Player_Input - 1] == 'O':
    Player_Input = int(input("Already taken. Choose another position: "))
```

Comment: How does it "not work"? Is there an error, or does it do nothing, or something else?

Comment: No there is no error. If I enter 1 and position 1 is already taken it does not even ask me to enter a new number. It stays there like it's an endless loop

Comment: The shown code snippets 2 and 3 wouldn't silently go into an endless loop. The problem is (at least partly) outside of these.

Comment: The issue here is you shouldn't be using a loop at all -- see my answer below for more detail.

Comment: I think I see what you were going for.. you wanted "repeat until they made a valid choice."  But that's not what you wrote.  I'll edit my answer a little more to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you're trying to use a `while` loop to assign `'X'` to the position they chose.  The purpose of a `while` loop isn't to do something to one particular known position in a list; it's to do something *repeatedly* for as long as a certain condition is met.  In your case, you know which space the player chose (based on the value of `Player_Input`), so using a `while` loop isn't the right approach.
Instead, just check if the chosen space (`Board[Player_Input - 1]`) hasn't been taken yet, and then assign the value.

Something like:

```
if Board[Player_Input - 1] != 'X' and Board[Player_Input - 1] != 'O':
   Board[Player_Input - 1] = 'X'  # assuming 'X' is the human player
else:
    # Handle the case where the space is full here.
```

**Edit:**

I think I may see now what you were going for with the loop -- you want something like "repeat until they made a valid choice".  One option would be to surround the code I wrote above with this:

```
while True: # Loop forever until we break out of it
    # Above code here
    if Board[Player_Input - 1] == 'X':
        break
```

**Edit 2:**

This should also work, and is perhaps closer to what you intended:

```
# Player chooses a space
Player_Input = int(input("Choose a number between 1-9: "))

# Available spaces should contain the space number, not 'X' or 'O'
# while choice not available: have player choose again
# (Should also add a check for if the input is not 1-9)
while Board[Player_Input - 1] != Player_Input:
    Player_Input = int(input("Already taken. Choose another position: "))

# Now that we know they made a valid choice, we fill in the players letter
Board[Player_Input - 1] = 'X'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :D This helped me fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
Board = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
count = 0
Player_Input = int(input("Choose a number between 1-9: "))
if Player_Input < 10 and Player_Input >= 1:
    for player in range(9):
        if Board[Player_Input - 1] == 'X' or Board[Player_Input - 1] == 'O':
            print('you cant use this number')
        if count % 2 == 0:
            Board[Player_Input - 1] = 'X'
        else:
            Board[Player_Input - 1] = 'O'
        def show():
            print(Board[0], '|', Board[1], '|', Board[2])
            print(Board[3], '|', Board[4], '|', Board[5])
            print(Board[6], '|', Board[7], '|', Board[8])
        print(show())
        Player_Input = int(input("Already taken. Choose another position: "))
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.